# Ship Movement Question Axis and Allies 1940 Global (Rules 2.0)

Tags: axis-and-allies

I have a question regarding the movement of ships. The explanation could get confusing so I will try to explain it clearly.

1. My ship, a cruiser, is attacked by an enemy fleet of destroyers moving from a naval port (total possible move of 3) during my opponent's turn.
2. Enemy ships all move two spaces to engage in combat.
3. During combat, my ship is destroyed.
4. After destroying my cruiser, my opponent **wants** to move the enemy fleet one more space into an adjacent sea zone containing 2 of my ships and initiate another combat phase during their turn.

Is my opponent allowed to do this move and then additional attack in one turn? If not, are they allowed to use their remaining move during their Non-Combat Movephase to move their ships into the seazone where my ships are?

Thanks for the help in advance. If you need more clarification please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 2 part answer to your question:

From the Rules (http://www.axisandallies.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Axis-Allies-Pacific-1940-Second-Edition.pdf):

> Move as many of your units into as many hostile territories and sea zones as
>   you wish. You can move into **a single hostile space** from different spaces, as
>   long as each moving unit can reach that space with a legal move.

I added in bold the important part. During your combat move, you can move into a single, hence only one hostile space. So no he cannot continue to move to a second hostile territory afterwards.

From the Non-combat move rules:

> In this phase, you can move any of your units **that didn’t
>   move** in the Combat Move phase or participate in combat
>   during your turn

Once again in bold, units that DIDN'T move can move in the non-combat phase.

Exception: I know that your question was about sea units, but tanks have a special "blitz" ability which allows them to continue moving after combat. Just look for the "blitz" ability in the units part of the rulebook.

Hope this answers your questions.